# Having problem with character ü in php/mysql on updated php/apache

Tags: php, mysql, forms, apache

I have an existing MySQL database from back in the PHP 4.x and 5.2 days where `latin1_swedish_ci` is the character set on the MySQL db/tables/columns (varchar) and php `default_charset` is blank.  This resulted with foreign chars like Chinese being entered with the &#; format.  For example entering 今井 in the form ends up  & #28009;& #19968; (I had to add space after the & or it actually looked like the characters in here) in the database.  Yes, using the encoded values use extra space but everything is already set that way.

The new server has `Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.10` and at first you couldn't look up the Chinese type characters because the new PHP used UTF8 in `default_charset` (I also had *MySQL Illegal mix of
collations* errors until changing database to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`).  So after finding the PHP `default_charset` was the problem, I changed `default_charset` to be blank and reverted the MySQL database to `latin_swedish_ci`.   All those type of things are working fine but I still have a problem with characters like `ü` (%FC).

For the `ü` (%FC) item, if I try to update the database, I can dump the variable right before the SQL update and it looks fine: `UPDATE table_name SET userFName='Günter' ...` but when it ends up in the database the `ü` becomes a `?` (question mark) for some reason.  On the old database/server, it updates correctly using the actual `ü` character.   Now on the opposite end, if I pull up an existing entry in the database that has the correct `ü` in the database (was there by importing from the old one), it shows up as `Ã¼` instead of the `ü` (looking it up in the database with phpMyAdmin it's the actual `ü`).

Can someone give me an idea of where the problem is?  I checked that the same character set is used on MySQL on both old and new (it's `latin1_swedish_ci`).  The only PHP changes from the old to the new was converting from `mysql_` versions to the `mysqli->` object based functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!!

That last part of my message, the only change was `mysql_` to `mysqli->` so I looked up character set support.  I found https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php and when checking what it reported, it reported `utf8mb4` for some reason, so I added `$mysqli->set_charset("latin1");` and now it's working like the old version was.   So if you are converting and have same issues, that's what it all is.

Maybe someday I'll create something to convert the &# format to actual UTF8.

Comment: Why are you using latin1? You should change everything to utf8mb4

Comment: because this has existed since the early 2000's.